# Are alphabetic optimality criteria (A,B,C,D) still valid in loglog regression models?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, experiment-design

Suppose we have the following model:

$$\log(\hat{y}_t)= \beta_2 + \beta_0 \times \log(x_{1, t}) + \beta_1 \times \log(x_{2, t})$$

We wish to choose $10$ design points where one design point can be noted as $\{x_{1, t}, x_{2, t}\}$.

---

I am wondering if the normal alphabetic criteria such as A,B,C,D-optimality apply to this setting where we have an loglog model.

Comment: I don't see why they wouldn't be, since we could frame this also as a change of variables (i.e. $y' = \mathbf X' \beta$). Since the optimality criteria don't (AFAIK) depend on anything about the distributions of the predictors (columns of $\mathbf X'$), everything ¿should? generalize just fine.